# How to find project files in a specific directory in Android Hedgehog

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

Finding a file under a specific directory was possible in previous versions of Android Studio.

Currently, I can only `find in files` by specifying directory, I can't search by files' names.

[image: android studio]

Changing Project Files dropdown at the right side does not do much, when I search like this, it finds library files makes it difficult to find my own files.

[image: android studio]

Comment: Searching files by specifying directory.
So if I want to find the files in specific package.

Comment: It is in the title, I updated the post anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to use this search pattern - "<part of folder name> / <part of file name>" (e.g. "org/Mai" for "src/org/Main.java")?

Comment: Thanks @y.bedrov unfortunately it still gets the Main.java in other folders

Comment: @EmreAkcan Can you provide an example of the results when you search for file with the folder specified?

Comment: @CrazyCoder if I search my-project/lib/ios, it finds files under my-project/ios as well, but it is still useful as it shows the closer files first